# Test Case failures with a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28526 with JDK 8 and terracotta 3.4.0

Tags: maven, java-8, indexoutofboundsexception, testcase, terracotta

I currently moved maven java code from jdk7 to jdk8 which uses terracotta and was working properly but after changing it to jdk8 , my test cases are getting failed. I am getting following error and I didn't get any clues through searching.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28526
at com.tc.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2015)
at com.tc.asm.ClassReader.getClassName(ClassReader.java:229)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(AsmClassInfo.java:305)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.createClassInfoFromStream(AsmClassInfo.java:717)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(AsmClassInfo.java:256)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getInterfaces(AsmClassInfo.java:558)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.regexp.TypePattern.matchInterfaces(TypePattern.java:147)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.regexp.TypePattern.matchInterfaces(TypePattern.java:147)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.regexp.TypePattern.matchSuperClasses(TypePattern.java:120)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.regexp.TypePattern.matchType(TypePattern.java:92)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.visit(ExpressionVisitor.java:437)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ast.ASTClassPattern.jjtAccept(ASTClassPattern.java:24)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.visitAnnotatedNode(ExpressionVisitor.java:1016)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.visit(ExpressionVisitor.java:237)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ast.ASTWithin.jjtAccept(ASTWithin.java:22)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.visit(ExpressionVisitor.java:100)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ast.ASTExpression.jjtAccept(ASTExpression.java:22)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.visit(ExpressionVisitor.java:88)
at com.tc.aspectwerkz.expression.ExpressionVisitor.match(ExpressionVisitor.java:74)
at com.tc.object.config.ClassExpressionMatcherImpl.match(ClassExpressionMatcherImpl.java:24)
at com.tc.object.config.CompoundExpressionMatcher.match(CompoundExpressionMatcher.java:18)
at com.tc.object.config.StandardDSOClientConfigHelperImpl.shouldBeAdapted(StandardDSOClientConfigHelperImpl.java:1242)
at com.tc.object.bytecode.hook.impl.DefaultWeavingStrategy.transformInternal(DefaultWeavingStrategy.java:184)
at com.tc.object.bytecode.hook.impl.DefaultWeavingStrategy.transform(DefaultWeavingStrategy.java:134)
at com.tc.object.bytecode.hook.impl.DSOContextImpl.preProcess(DSOContextImpl.java:288)
at com.tc.object.bytecode.hook.impl.DSOContextImpl.transform(DSOContextImpl.java:392)
at org.terracotta.express.ClusteredStateLoader.transform(ClusteredStateLoader.java:124)
at org.terracotta.express.ClusteredStateLoader.loadClass(ClusteredStateLoader.java:83)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory$1.call(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:319)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory$1.call(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:317)
at org.terracotta.api.Terracotta.lookupOrCreateRoot(Terracotta.java:47)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.getStoreRoot(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:316)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.getStoreMapForCacheManager(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:77)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.getOrCreateStore(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:68)
at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.createStore(TerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:64)
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.createStore(StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:40)
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems comming from a wrong match pattern: aspectwerkz.expression.regexp.TypePattern.matchInterfaces(TypePattern.java:147) , and if you get up it seems comming from your config: StandardDSOClientConfigHelperImpl , this is the only things I can give. Need more information

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am running the performance test cases in eclipse and getting this exception, please let me know if any other info is needed.

Comment: I’d say, update you version of Terracotta to a Java 8 compliant one. First Google Hit: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/11437.page (says fixed somewhere between 3.7.7 and 3.7.10)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, Terracotta 3.4.0 is not Java 8 compatible and given the way the old Terracotta version worked, this is not a surprise.

You will have to update to a [later version](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog) if you must have Java 8 support.

The exact version will depend on the usage you are making of Terracotta - if you need DSO support, you have to stick with the 3.7.x line.
For Ehcache support, it is recommended to upgraded to the latest version in the 4.3.x line.